# Global Variables and Accessing Object Attributes

Tags: javascript, api, object

I'm trying to do two things and I'm unable to do one of them by themselves.
I want to use a global variable in a function.
And I want to change some attributes within the said global variable.

A button triggers 'getLocation', which triggers 'storePosition', which triggers 'mapScreen', which triggers 'moveMapToInitialPoint'.

I'm using the here maps API and I'm trying to get the user location and set the map around it.

For problem 1, I tried moving the variable inside the function, however, I will be using this variable many times throughout the function. I also tried adding 'global.', 'this.', and 'globalthis.' before the variable. It's really confusing because my next function is able to access the global variable just fine.

For problem 2, I tried using 'initialPoint[lat]' but it says lat can't be found. I also tried creating a new object with its attribute set to the position objects.

I also tried the instructions on the documentation as well as the other stack questions but it's not working.

```
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(storePosition);
  } else {
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.")
  }
}

initialPoint = {lat:39.9522, lng:-75.1932};
function storePosition(position) {
  initialPoint.lat = position.coords.latitude;
  initialPoint.lng = position.coords.longitude;
  mapScreen();
}

function moveMapToInitialPoint(map){
  map.setCenter(initialPoint);
  map.setZoom(14);
}

moveMapToInitialPoint(map);
```

I just want the map to revolve around the user but it either shows the entire world because the points are broken, or it shows the default location.

Comment: I'm using Cordova for hybrid development and visual studio for javascript and windows 10 and ios latest one for the operating systems if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
initialPoint = {lat:39.9522, lng:-75.1932};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback, calldown);
function callback(position) {
  initialPoint.lat = position.coords.latitude;
  initialPoint.lng = position.coords.longitude;
  moveMapToInitialPoint(map);
}

function calldown() {
  moveMapToInitialPoint(map);
}

function moveMapToInitialPoint(map){
  map.setCenter(initialPoint);
  map.setZoom(14);
}
```

Comment: I tried moving the moveMapToInitialPoint outside the functions but it gets called first for some reason. If anyone can it, that would be nice.